RuffleでHTML/JavaScriptとムービーの連携を行ないたい
FlashエミュレータRuffleについて調べたいのですが、国内サイトにはほとんど情報が無く、公式ドキュメントもほんのわずかしか無く、困っています。
一番知りたいのは、FlashムービーとJavaScriptとの連携ができないことです。
Flash Playerの時代には、JavaScriptで swfObj.GotoFrame(フレーム番号); とすれば指定フレームに移動できていましたし、ActionScriptからExternalInterfaceを公開すると、JavaScript側からActionScriptの関数を実行させることができました。
（辛うじてActionScript→JavaScriptの連携は、ActionScriptの「getURL」で可能なようでした）
Ruffleで生成したムービーオブジェクトに対して使えるメソッドは以下のページで確認できましたが、callExternalInterfaceを使ってみても「そんなメソッドは無い」と返されるばかりです。
https://ruffle.rs/js-docs/master/interfaces/Player.PlayerV1.html
とにかくRuffleに関する技術情報が無さすぎるので、Ruffleに関するコミュニティ・フォーラムがあるならそれを見つけたいのですが、教えていただけるでしょうか。
